# What is the DOM Node Count in google chrome's developer tools timeline memory view?

Tags: performance, google-chrome

I'm getting an "Aw, snap!" chrome crash when a certain webpage is being loaded. I'm trying my best to figure out what's causing it and having a really hard time.

In the Chrome Developer's tool there is a Memory Tab and when looking at the counter graphs, I notice that the DOM Node Count line steps up, drops, and then continues to rise.

[image: Dom node count increasing]

I understood this to mean that the DOM element counts on my page were increasing but after doing

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").length
```

in the console I noticed the value wasn't changing.

So what is the DOM Node count graph actually showing? If it continues increasing like this, could that potentially be the cause of the "Aw, snap!" crash?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The DOM node count graph shows the number of created DOM nodes that are still held in memory, i.e. which have not been garbage collected yet. This doesn't have to coincide with the elements you get through `getElementsByTagName`. The latter will also only get you the elements actually attached to the document tree. It won't get any 'offline' items to which you still have references.

An easy way to get stuck with this particular pyramid growth is the Like widget from the Facebook API, which contains some code on a run-away timer that creates boatloads of additional DOM nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Turns out I was doing something similar as to what you described with the facebook api.

Comment: Could you explain what `DOM nodes that are still held in memory` means?  So, for example, there are ~700 DOM nodes on my page and the DOM node count graph shows ~5k.  Are there intermediate DOM nodes created as the HTML is being built?

Answer (score 11):

*DOM nodes that are still held in memory* are so called detached nodes. This means they are not shown in the DOM tree of your page, but some JavaScript code still references them somewhere. Read through this google dev tools post that explains what Detached DOM nodes are with simple code and how to detect it using Chrome DevTools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Comment: I'm testing my (angular 6) application, I do the following steps: GC, create some components, delete the added components, GC.
I'm noticing that the number of nodes in the performance tab keep increasing, even if the number of Detatched Nodes doesn't change before/after the test...