# What's a good way to figure out which code is causing runaway DOM node creation?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools

The Chrome Dev Tools have unearthed some problems [similar to those posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901730/what-is-the-dom-node-count-in-google-chromes-developer-tools-timeline-memory-vi), more DOM nodes being created than I feel should be given my design choices.

[image: Dom node count increasing]

What's a good way to figure out what area of code is causing runaway DOM node creation? The information is really useful but figuring out what to do with it seems much less straightforward than, for example, dealing with a CPU profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking two heap snapshots (the `Profiles` panel), one with few DOM nodes and one with lots of them, then compare and see if many nodes are retained. If yes, you will be able to detect the primary retainers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating code that walks the DOM and collects some statistics about what nodes are in the DOM (tag type, class name, id value, parent, number of children, textContent, etc...).  If you know what is supposed to be in your page, you should be able to look at this data dump and determine what's in there that you aren't expecting.  You could even run the code at page load time, then run it again after your page has been exercised a bit and compare the two.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("*").length` shows a stable number of nodes. This is a MVC-style (Backbone.js) issue: I've got `render()` methods hooked to change events and one of them is rendering and replacing itself too often.

Comment: @editor - You could also have DOM nodes that aren't in inserted in the DOM, but were created and there are references to them stored in javascript variables (which keeps them from being garbage collected).

Comment: @jfriend00 do you have such a snippet or library?

Comment: @user3919920 - You can just call `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` and then examine all that tags you get.  For example, you could count how many tags you have of each type.  It's not clear exactly what problem you're trying to solve so I'd suggest you post your own question where you describe your exact problem.  Depending upon what exactly you're trying to do, heap snapshots might be useful too.