# Where are these DOM nodes coming from when only changing innerText?

Tags: javascript, innertext, dom-node

I created a simple loop using seInterval. Every time it calls the timeout function it sets the innerText property of an h1 element.

when I monitor the performance in chrome dev tools I can see that the DOM node count increases every time the timeout function is called, but more specifically when the innerText is assigned.

I'm wondering if changing the innerText property always creates new DOM nodes that are later cleaned up or if I am just not understanding something about innerText or how the DOM works.

[image]

Edit: I should mention that once the node count reaches about 1500 it drops back down to the starting count. I assume this is the garbage collector working.

(I just noticed that this doesn't happen when running the code snippet below, but it does when opening the file in the browser.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="title">
    HELLO
</h1>
<script>
  const title = document.querySelector('.title');
  title.innerText = 'HELLO';

  function onTimeout() {
    title.innerText = title.innerText === "HELLO" ? "BYE" : "HELLO";
  }
  setInterval(onTimeout, 500);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried the more standard [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerText` as [they are different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)?

Comment: Where are you seeing the DOM Nodes graph in dev tools? Also which browser is this?

Comment: textContent has the same effect on node count. This graph is from the chrome dev tools under the performance tab and at the bottom, there is another tab called performance monitor. It might be hidden away.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901730/what-is-the-dom-node-count-in-google-chromes-developer-tools-timeline-memory-vi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only nodes that contains "raw" text are those implementing [CharacterData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData) interface, thus only [Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text), [Comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment) and [CDATASection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection) nodes. Regular elements will use at least one of the mentioned nodes for textual content. Thus, no matter will use you [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), there always will be inserted a new [Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) node. To circumvent this you may change the textContent of Text node that was previously inserted, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="title">
    HELLO
</h1>
<script>
  const title = document.querySelector('.title');
  title.textContent = 'HELLO';

  function onTimeout() {
    title.firstChild.textContent = title.textContent === "HELLO" ? "BYE" : "HELLO";
  }
  setInterval(onTimeout, 500);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question. can you answer a quick follow-up? If I keep it the way it was in my example and just let the nodes get removed periodically (I assume by the garbage collector) would that be considered bad practice? Or is the example you have here the better option when changing text?

Comment: Does anyone actually do this?  Is there a reason to?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your way of doing as far as performance is not a concern, but for ultimate performance this is a must. And yes, many performant libraries like Vue, or Solid are doing this, I also am doing this in the [UI library](https://karyon.dev) I have developed ;). Consider [this example](https://karyon.dev/workbench/#examples/sierpinski-triangle), it will run slower if doing updates of numbers held by the vertexes using textContent.